# write_xlsx GEM RUBY insert checkbox in a cell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xlsxwriter

I am using `ruby 2.5.5` and `write_xlsx gem version: 0.85.6` for creating dynamic Excel sheets in ruby.

My problem is simple, I want to insert a checkbox is a cell. I know we can have drop down using data_validation also we can have button. But what I need is a simple checkbox which is default false and can be checked as value TRUE.

I hope my question is clear and to the point.

example code:

```
wb = WriteXLSX.new(filename)
format = Report.format_workbook(wb)
ws = wb.add_worksheet(ws_title)
Report.setup_worksheet(ws)
ws.tab_color = 'yellow'
rt.next_row
ws.merge_range(rt.row, 0, rt.row, 1, "Hours", format[:field_label_bg_orange_bold_center])

ws.write(rt.row, 3, "Booked", format[:bold_right_border])
ws.write(rt.row, 4, "0", format[:bold_center_12_border1])

ws.data_validation(rt.row, 7, {'validate': 'custom', 'value': '=AND(F5=50,G5=60)'})
ws.data_validation(rt.row, 8, {'validate': 'list',
  'source': ['TRUE', 'FALSE'],
  })
  ws.write(rt.row, 8, 'FALSE')

rt.next_row
ws.merge_range(rt.row, 0, rt.row, 1, "Some text goes here", format[:center])
///At this point I want to insert a checkbox
```

Comment: write_xlsx is a Ruby port of Excel::Writer::XLSX which doesn’t support checkboxes. So write_xlsx doesn’t support them.

Comment: @jmcnamara So any other option?
Is it achievable in "google_drive gem"?
Or anything you can suggest? That would be really helpful for me.